# responsive image in Material Design Lite

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, material-design-lite

I'm porting a design made for Bootstrap into MDL (don't ask). I'm trying to find some equivalent mechanism for implementing bootstrap's `.img-responsive` functionality in MDL, but I keep coming up short. Is there a standard way to do this, or do I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> while I agree that's a way to do this, i'm looking to see if there's an MDL-standard way

I was looking for the same and dug up a bit more, [from the docs](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/820) (here they are referring to cards and the images inside at first):

> For simplicity we opted to set a hard width and allow developers to override that as-needed since there is no set right way to have responsive cards display.

There is also a mention of using the picture tag, you might want to [check support first](https://caniuse.com/#search=picture)...

[@JakeC1020](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2129695/jakec1020) Answer is a correct implementation for now then.

Answer (score 1):

From [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images):

> ### Responsive images
>
> Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition of the `.img-responsive` class. This applies `max-width: 100%;`, `height: auto;` and `display: block;` to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.

This means that it should be fairly strait forward to roll your own:

```
.img-responsive {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

This of course assumes some kind of parent div to scale accordingly like a col-md-* would in bootstrap.

Comment: while I agree that's *a* way to do this, i'm looking to see if there's an MDL-standard way.